# Plugin won't output characters with diacritics properly

Tags: php, plugin-development, encoding

I'm developing a custom plugin for a Wordpress based website.
I have a function that will output some html to the site like this:

```
function display_content()
{
    $content = '<div><p>Śóme ćóńtęńt with diąćritićś</p></div>';
    return $content;
}

add_shortcode('my_shortcode', 'display_content');
```

On the website the output of this shortcode will have all the characters with diacritics replaced by '�'. The content that is not generated by the plugin does not have this issue. The characters look fine in the source code too.

It's some encoding problem, but I can't find what is the source of it. Is Wordpress or the server misconfigured? Am I doing something wrong with this plugin?

I looked online but it's extremely hard to find anything in the 1000s of results about wrong encoding in the database. I don't think this applies here since the content from the database looks fine, but I'm pretty new to WP and I might be wrong here.

Comment: Make sure your PHP files are encoded in **UTF-8 without BOM**.

Comment: @fuxia Thank you! This was the problem. My IDE (PHPStorm) was showing UTF-8, but it turns out it doesn't show if it has BOM or not.

Comment: Also, be mindful that technically those diacritics should be HTML encoded rather than output raw

Comment: @TomJNowell Persistent storage - like a file - should not use a output specific escaping. You do that only when you are actually creating the output.